# How can one delete ONLY files in specific folders matching a regular expression in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

We have two companies, in two separate containers in AD, accessing one shared directory for all of their scan files. We need to have an automated script run every night, and purge ONLY the files from the user folders in one companies AD container (Office1). I found a very helpful script on here that I was able to modify to match and delete the folders for these specific users, but I need this to be able to delete just the files in these folders only.

Here is the script:

```
$UserNames = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Office1,DC=US,DC=parent,DC=net" |
             Select -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
$UserRegex = ($UserNames | ForEach {[RegEx]::Escape($_)}) -join "|"
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\share\scanfiles\Test" -Directory -Recurse |
    Where {$_.Name -match $UserRegex -and !$_.PSIsContainer} |
    Remove-Item -Force
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
Get-ChildItem -Path "\\share\scanfiles\Test" -Directory -Recurse |
  Where { $_.Name -Match $UserRegex } | 
    ForEach-Object { Remove-Item "$($_.FullName)\*" -Force -WhatIf }
```

`-WhatIf` previews what would be deleted; remove it to perform actual deletion.

Note how the first 2 segments of the pipeline output *directory* objects only, whereas the last segment then deletes the files *inside* each directory.